# stretched image with proc gslide (with correct dimension values)

Tags: graph, sas, sas-ods

I need to create an image contains two plots.
What I am doing is outputting both them into a folder on my pc as a gif file.
The first one is like a screen of a proc report using ods=printer dpi=300

```
data sociodem;
length ID COL  AGE sex race var1 var2 var3 $15;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input ID  COL AGE SEX RACE var1 var2 var3;
datalines;
1,01,50,MALE,ASIAN,AAAA,BBBB,12345, 
;

option printerpath=gif nodate nonumber;
option papersize=('8in','1.2in')
ods printer file='\\.\.\first.gif' dpi=300;
proc report data=sociodem nowd; where id='1'; run;
ods printer close;
ods listing;
```

the second one is another graph created with a proc template / proc sgrender, also here is a gif but with ods graphics, but I won't stay on this.

The fact is that when I'm trying to import the first graph back into SAS (I will merge them with proc greplay),

```
goptions reset=all noborder  xmax = 8in xpixels = 2400 ymax = 1.2in ypixels = 360 hsize=8in vsize=1.2in device=png300;
proc gslide IFRAME = "\\.\.\first.gif" imagestyle=tile gout=grfcat name='text'; 
title;
footnote;
run;
quit;
```

in the catalog grfcat I import it stretched, but it seems good in my folder and the dimension and dpi seems set the right way.

Anyone knows how to import it avoiding stretching?
I also tried

```
imagestyle=fit
```

and a lot of other options that hasn't solved my problem.